# New Relic Python alternative?

Tags: python, newrelic, nagios, munin

I'm looking for an alternative to New Relic That I could host by myself in Python or with a Free plan as Sentry.

I already use Sentry free plan for bugs trace and it is really a must have for our framework (Django). (getsentry.com)

I'm looking for the other side, the dark side. Monitoring bandwidth servers, cpu, memory and applications like Redis, Postgresql, Varnish, etc.

Munin does the job but it is getting really old and it is a pain to install.

Comment: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/